# Finding record with most complete columns

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table that currently narrows down records to only unique contacts, and it works, but I am still left with similar records of that unique contact due to spelling errors. Some "duplicates" have null or empty columns.

I want to fix this by finding the record that has the most columns filled in (despite accuracy), exclude the rest? Should multiple columns have the same amount filled in, have it choose based on the most recent creation date. Is there a way to do this?

```
fileid    datecreated    first    middle    last    phone    
00001     2015-11-16     bob      null      smith   555-5555
00002     2013-18-7      BOB                SMITHE           
00003     2015-11-1      Bobb     B         Smith   555-5555
00004     2014-5-23      bob      smith             NULL
```

I was thinking I'd start by using COUNT(), but I'm not sure if that would be right.

Comment: This is a HUGE project.

Comment: As Strawberry mentioned this could be huge. Look for levenshtein distance and lucene in asp.net. Let me know if you need more details. Refer to this http://levenshtein.blogspot.com/

Comment: Depending on how many of these duplicate rows you have, I would be tempted to do this manually. I'd then shore up the app and db logic to make sure it doesn't happen again.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you get started. Assign a 1 or 0 to each column based on whether it is NULL or empty. Get a sum for the row. Order or this sum and then by date.

```
select top 1 *
from 
    (select 
        *
      , CASE WHEN fileid IS NULL or fileid = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN datecreated IS NULL or datecreated = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN first IS NULL or first = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN middle IS NULL or middle = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN last IS NULL or last = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END +
        CASE WHEN phone IS NULL or phone = '' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS NumFilled
    from 
      YourTable) yt
order by numfilled, datecreated desc
```